# How to get only physical video input devices in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I want to get video input devices from a webapp. I want to filter out virtual cameras.

```
await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true });
let devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
devices = devices.filter((device) => device.kind == "videoinput");
```

I can get the list of devices this way. But they also include virtual cameras.

I could use label property to check if it contains 'virtual' text. But users can name it without word 'virtual'. So it's not a good enough solution.

Is there a way to get only physical webcams(exclude virtual cameras)?

Comment: That would be bad UX, it defeats the purpose of having virtual cameras. Also, even if you could, it wouldn't say much because you could be running in a VM and your "physical" camera may be actually virtually nonetheless.

Comment: @CherryDT In my case I need to not let users use virtual cams.

Comment: Sorry, that's not up to you.

Comment: @ShehanDMG It's their computer, they can use whatever they want. You can't limit that. If it even were possible, I would be annoyed if your software would do this and I would simply inject a userscript that patches the function to declare all cameras as physical and bypass it this way. There is no way you can prevent somebody from using a virtual camera.